# Roles of Python in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am a Trainee in a company learning Python. The company wants me to study `Python` and `Google App Engine`. I studied them both individually and even  used Google App Engine to create Web application with Bootstrap and JavaScript.

However, I do not know how to use Python in Google App Engine. When or where I should used Python in Google App Engine? What is the role of Python in making a Web Application?

Comment: I just clone the appengine-guestbook-python in Google App Engine as it will generate me the folder automatically... I've seen the .py in the folder but I do not know the role of it..

Comment: Is there any reference (site teaching python related to web application or pdf) you can give me so I can study it, that I will be able to understand it?Please.

Comment: What do you mean you don't know the role of .py files?

Comment: @Nishant could you add your comment as an answer, please?

Answer (score 1):

Python will act as a *middleware* between the *front-end* and the *database* usually serving as a Web Server (whose job is to handle requests) and an Application Server (whose job is to do the business logic and optionally add a security layer).

```
browser -> web-server(python?) -> app-server(python?) -> database -> browser
```

In small projects like a Flask App, Web Server and Application Server are the same. But this can run into scalability problems.

You said you already created a web application, how did you access it in the browser?

Instead of worrying about terminologies just try out some **Hello World** examples and things will be clear.